# 'Integral2' error in MATLAB for invalid integrand

Tags: matlab, integration, sage, numerical-integration

Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
syms z_1 z_2 m_1 m_2 x y Q p s t
m_1=0.01;
m_2=249;
x=5;
y=5;
Q=0.6;
p=0.5;
s=0.04;
t=0.25;
func=(62001*sinh(y/100 - z_2/100))/(100*cosh((249*cos(2*pi*(z_1 - x + 1/4)))/2 +249))-(249*sinh(249*y - 249*z_2))/(10000*(cosh((249*cos(2*pi*(z_1 - x + 1/4)))/2 + 249) - 620009999/10000)); 
hunc=(m_1*m_2*(Q+p*cos(2*pi*(x-z_1-t))))/(m_2^3*tanh(m_1*(1+p*cos(2*pi*(x-z_1-t))))-m_1^3*tanh(m_2*(1+p*cos(2*pi*(x-z_1-t))))-(1+p*cos(2*pi*(x-z_1-t))*m_1*m_2*(m_2^2-m_1^2)));
lunc=3/(2*pi*s^2*t^3)*exp(-(3*z_1^2/(2*s^2*t^3))+(3*z_2^2/(2*s^2*t^3)));
F=func*hunc*lunc;
integral2(F,-inf,inf,-inf,inf)
```

I am getting that the error that

`Integrand is invalid`

in MATLAB console. Though the integrand is long, I hope it has all the correct symbols.
As a side, I put the same function and integrated it in SageMath, but I got an answer very close to zero. What exactly is wrong in the integrand or method? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Are you really getting this error in matlab? For me it just complains immediately that `F` isn't a function handle, which is correct (you don't actually give any hint towards what are the integration variables here). It also expects this to be numerically evaluated, not symbolically. It seems unclear what you actually want here.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman yes, I want to numerically evaluate the function $F$. For simplicity, I split it into a product of three functions. The variables of integrations are $z_1, z_2$. Should I remove syms declaration?

Comment: @MikaelÖhman I tried using `@(z_1,z_2) F` and deleting `syms ` and the variables after it. Still getting error. The errors are numerous, `ScalarValued`, `Vadapt` errors are just two of the several errors I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to evaluate this numerically there is no need to involve symbolic math, and we can just write functions;

```matlab
func=@(z_1,z_2) (62001*sinh(y/100 - z_2/100))/(100*cosh((249*cos(2*pi*(z_1 - x + 1/4)))/2 +249))-(249*sinh(249*y - 249*z_2))/(10000*(cosh((249*cos(2*pi*(z_1 - x + 1/4)))/2 + 249) - 620009999/10000)); 
hunc=@(z_1,z_2) (m_1*m_2*(Q+p*cos(2*pi*(x-z_1-t))))/(m_2^3*tanh(m_1*(1+p*cos(2*pi*(x-z_1-t))))-m_1^3*tanh(m_2*(1+p*cos(2*pi*(x-z_1-t))))-(1+p*cos(2*pi*(x-z_1-t))*m_1*m_2*(m_2^2-m_1^2)));
lunc=@(z_1,z_2) 3/(2*pi*s^2*t^3)*exp(-(3*z_1^2/(2*s^2*t^3))+(3*z_2^2/(2*s^2*t^3)));
F=@(z_1,z_2) func(z_1,z_2)*hunc(z_1,z_2)*lunc(z_1,z_2);
```

However, before integration, I tested just evaluating this complicated function for a few random points

```matlab
>> F(1,2)
ans =
  -Inf
>> F(1,3)
ans =
  -Inf
>> F(1,1)
ans =
  -Inf
>> F(1,0)
ans =
   NaN
>> F(0,0)
ans =
  -Inf
```

I've yet to find any inputs where this is well behaved.

Comment: Thanks, but still I get lot of errors.  Pasting the same here:
Error in contour>@(z_1,z_2)3/(2*pi*s^2*t^3)*exp(-(3*z_1^2/(2*s^2*t^3))+(3*z_2^2/(2*s^2*t^3))) (line 11)
lunc=@(z_1,z_2) 3/(2*pi*s^2*t^3)*exp(-(3*z_1^2/(2*s^2*t^3))+(3*z_2^2/(2*s^2*t^3)));

Error in contour>@(z_1,z_2)func(z_1,z_2)*hunc(z_1,z_2)*lunc(z_1,z_2) (line 12)
F= @(z_1,z_2) func(z_1,z_2)*hunc(z_1,z_2)*lunc(z_1,z_2);

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 237)
            Z1 = FUN(X(VTSTIDX),Y(VTSTIDX)); NFE = NFE + 1; Contd....

Comment: Errors contd....
Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 9)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral2 (line 105)
    Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);

Error in contour (line 13)
integral2(F,-100,100,-100,100)

Comment: What do you expect from a function that is `-Inf` or `NaN`  everywhere?

Comment: Actually the function becoming divergent is irritating me. Like, we have none of the functions individually singular (hyperbolic, sine and cosine functions). Then, how the function be this misbehaved? So which portion of the function is the real reason of divergence. Like then I could somehow modify that portion.  By the way, in SageMath, the integral evaluates smoothly to a very small quantity

Comment: `exp(1000)` becomes `Inf` with double precision math. I don't know what sagemath does. I suspect this isn't well posed for numerical evaluation.

Comment: Oh! Ok, so that means the function has very small values. So will multiplication of the function by any factor help?

Comment: I don't know, these expressions are pretty much completely unreadable I'm afraid.